# Successfully using jScrollpane and Colorbox plugins together

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, colorbox, jscrollpane

Has anyone managed to get these two plugins working together:

http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html

http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/

Am having no luck with the following:

```
// Colorbox dialog window
$('.w_price_assess p.price_report > a').colorbox({
    title: "Price report",
    transition: "elastic",
    innerWidth: "800px",
    innerHeight: "699px",
    opacity: "0.5",
    onLoad: function() {
        $('#cboxContent').jScrollPane({
            showArrows: true,
            scrollbarWidth: 13,
            scrollbarMargin: 0
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to achieve this myself by calling jScrollPane when colorbox had finished loading the content.

Use onComplete event in colorbox and not onLoad like above.